# Extracting part of a string up to a specific character in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string containing a name and address lines, with a `<br />` tag separating the name and each address line.  For instance:

```
John Smith<br />999 Somewhere Lane<br />City, FL 66600
```

I want to separate the name from the rest of the address using PHP.  Is this something that can be done?

Comment: explode on the <br />

Comment: Reword to make text shorted and clearer.  Quote the `<br />` tag so it does not disappear in the displayed version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case the simplest would be to use explode:

```
$str = 'John Smith<br />999 Somewhere Lane<br />City, FL 66600';
$tmp = explode('<br />', $str);
$name = $tmp[0];
```

You may, of course use regex but this is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

explode or substr with strpos

```
$str = 'John Smith<br />999 Somewhere Lane<br />City, FL 66600';
echo substr($str,0,strpos($str,'<br />')); //John Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the data even though it looked like this `<br>, <br/> <br  />`, etc.

```
$text = "John Smith<br />999 Somewhere Lane<br />City, FL 66600"

$data = preg_split("/\<br(\s+)?(\/)?\>/", $text);
print_r($data);

Array
(
    [0] => John Smith
    [1] => 999 Somewhere Lane
    [2] => City, FL 66600
)
```